# GCP Kubernetes, not allow me to create POD with requested CPU resources less than 250m

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cpu

Deployments to GCP Kubernetes, are getting automatically "requested CPU" as 250m, no matter what provided in yaml file. (for values less than 250)

example:
create a name space
`kubectl create namespace testnamespace`

create and deploy following dummy pod
test.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-node
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-node
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-node
          image: nginx
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

`kubectl apply -f test.yaml --namespace=testnamespace`

with or without configured LimitRange, the actual pod request 250m of CPU.

Part of deployed yaml file from K8s, which prove that the deployed pod is not following the provided yaml file

```
     image: nginx
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 250m
          ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
          memory: 512Mi
```

I also try to setup LimitRange on specific namespace, but the behavior remains the same. Sample of LimitRange is below.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: resource-limits
spec:
  limits:
    - type: Pod
      max:
        cpu: 2
      min:
        cpu: 10m
    - type: Container
      max:
        cpu: 2
      min:
        cpu: 10m
      default:
        cpu: 1
      defaultRequest:
        cpu: 20m
      maxLimitRequestRatio:
        cpu: 10
```

This is critical as i want to create a microservices environment, with lot of small services, which each one occupy 25% of the CPU even on their idle mode.

Comment: After lot of reading, was a paragraph in GCP autopilot, that was describing what i was facing. 
```https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-resource-requests#min-max-requests```
so, if you have any alternative for microservices environments, please share